# How to add conditional code in Android.bp

Tags: build, android-source

AOSP now has new build system, and file `Android.bp` has replaced `Android.mk` in many places.

Now I want to list source files conditionally depending on platform.

Say something like this:

```
if(atom)
{
   src: [
      .......list of files.......
   ],
   exclude_srcs: [
      .......list of files.......
   ]
} else
{
   src: [
      .......list of files.......
   ],
   exclude_srcs: [
      .......list of files.......
   ]
}
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this?
Also, how can I achieve logical operations like `NOT`, `OR` etc in conditionals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from documentation:

> By design, Android.bp files are very simple. There are **no conditionals or control flow statements** - any complexity is handled in build logic written in Go.

You can read it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/).

Comment: The same document suggests using map to replace conditional statements. The example shows how different sources can be set for arm and x86.

Comment: That true, I was more answering to the question in topic than suggesting solution for OP, so thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: For whose who decide to remove conditionals as recommended, I suggest them to read the following best practices : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/best_practices.md#removing-conditionals

Comment: soong_config_module_type seems to be the recommended way but it's only supported from Android 11.

Answer (score 2):

***GO***

You can write a go script with your conditions. Follow

[Is there a way to add/remove module in Android.bp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423380/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-module-in-android-bp)

[What is art.go? And why is it considered a way to write conditionals in bp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files)

***Conditional compilation***

If you just want to include a module conditionally you can define many `Android.bp` modules and include them based on conditions in `Android.mk` files.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/best_practices.md#removing-conditionals

***soong_config_modules***

You will face parsing errors if any of your `Android.bp` files include libraries not supported by your AOSP.

To fix that you can use `soong_config_modules`. Note that this is supported only `Android 11 R` onwards.

Details are given in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/android/soong_config_modules.go

However, I'll give you an example.

Here I am including special libraries when the AOSP is Android 12. Since these libraries might not be present on lower versions, I will not include `iot-camera-system.mk` in `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` so it will not be included as a preinstalled app.

What specifically I will achieve with `soong_config_modules` is removal of parsing errors when these libraries are not present (Android parses all `Android.bp` files to form a parse tree, it also checks for the existence of their dependencies and build fails when they are not present).

**iot-camera-system.mk**

```
# CameraApp Android Application Package

ifeq ($(PLATFORM_VERSION), $(filter $(PLATFORM_VERSION),S 12))
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += CameraApp
  SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := newCameraTarget
else
  SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := oldCameraTarget
endif
```

**Android.bp**

```
// This introduces the module type camera_cc_defaults
// If target.mk file contained:
//
// SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
// SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
// SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := newCameraTarget
//
// Then our libs would build with static_libs

soong_config_module_type {
    name: "camera_cc_defaults",
    module_type: "cc_defaults",
    config_namespace: "camera",
    variables: ["camtargets"],
    properties: ["static_libs"],
}

soong_config_string_variable {
    name: "camtargets",
    values: ["oldCameraTarget", "newCameraTarget"],
}

camera_cc_defaults {
    name: "camera_defaults",
    soong_config_variables: {
        camtargets: {
            oldCameraTarget: {
                static_libs: [
                ],
            },
            newCameraTarget: {
                static_libs: [
                    "androidx.core_core-ktx",
                    "androidx.fragment_fragment-ktx",
                    "androidx.navigation_navigation-fragment-ktx",
                    "androidx.navigation_navigation-ui-ktx",
                    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime-ktx",
                    "kotlinx_coroutines",
                    "kotlinx_coroutines_android",
                ],
            },
        },
    },
}

android_library {
  name: "utils",
  defaults: ["camera_defaults"],
  manifest: "utils/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
  platform_apis: true,

  srcs: [
    "utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/*.kt",
  ],

  resource_dirs: [
    "utils/src/main/res/",
  ],

  static_libs: [
    "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
    "androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager",
    "com.google.android.material_material",
    "androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface",
    "androidx.core_core",
    "androidx.preference_preference",
    "androidx.fragment_fragment",
    "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions",
    "kotlin-stdlib",
    "kotlin-reflect",
    "gson-prebuilt-jar",
  ],

  optimize: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}

android_app {
  name: "CameraApp",
  defaults: ["camera_defaults"],
  manifest: "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
  privileged: true,
  platform_apis: true,
  certificate: "platform",

  srcs: [
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/*.kt",
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/fragments/*.kt",
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/overlay/*.kt",
  ],

  resource_dirs: [
    "app/src/main/res/",
  ],

  static_libs: [
    "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
    "androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager",
    "com.google.android.material_material",
    "androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface",
    "androidx.core_core",
    "androidx.preference_preference",
    "androidx.fragment_fragment",
    "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions",
    "kotlin-stdlib",
    "kotlin-reflect",
    "gson-prebuilt-jar",
    "utils",
  ],

  optimize: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this a sample on how to add a conditional in a bp file:

```
cc_library {  
    ...  
    srcs: ["generic.cpp"],  
    arch: {  
        arm: {  
            srcs: ["arm.cpp"],  
        },  
        x86: {  
            srcs: ["x86.cpp"],  
        },  
    },  
}
```

Comment: So, you're using some of the builtin logic to select stuff based on architecture. Not an answer to the general question regarding how to manage conditionals, though.