# How do I add condition in Android.bp

Tags: android, compilation, android-source, android-soong

I want to differentiate code between Android Q and Android R how do I achieve this in Android.bp?
In Android.mk I did something like this

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM_VERSION), R)
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_R_AOSP
else
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_Q_AOSP
```

How to do above code in Android.bp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is art.go? And why is it considered a way to write conditionals in bp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files).

Replace this part in the `my_defaults.go`:

```
    if ctx.AConfig().Getenv("SOME_ENV_VAR") == "some_value" {
        cflags = append(cflags, "-DCONDITIONAL")
    }
```

With:

```
    if ctx.AConfig().PlatformVersionName() == "R" {
        cflags = append(cflags, "-DANDROID_R_AOSP")
    } else {
        cflags = append(cflags, "-DANDROID_Q_AOSP")
    }
```

Reference: [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/android10-dev/android/config.go#489). In older versions this function was called `PlatformVersion()` ([link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r75/android/config.go#369)), but for Android 9 or higher you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

***GO***

You can write a go script with your conditions. Follow

[Is there a way to add/remove module in Android.bp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423380/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-module-in-android-bp)

[What is art.go? And why is it considered a way to write conditionals in bp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files)

***Conditional compilation***

If you just want to include a module conditionally you can define many `Android.bp` modules and include them based on conditions in `Android.mk` files.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/best_practices.md#removing-conditionals

***soong_config_modules***

You will face parsing errors if any of your `Android.bp` files include libraries not supported by your AOSP.

To fix that you can use `soong_config_modules`. Note that this is supported only `Android 11 R` onwards.

Details are given in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/android/soong_config_modules.go

However, I'll give you an example.

Here I am including special libraries when the AOSP is Android 12. Since these libraries might not be present on lower versions, I will not include `iot-camera-system.mk` in `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` so it will not be included as a preinstalled app.

What specifically I will achieve with `soong_config_modules` is removal of parsing errors when these libraries are not present (Android parses all `Android.bp` files to form a parse tree, it also checks for the existence of their dependencies and build fails when they are not present).

**iot-camera-system.mk**

```
# CameraApp Android Application Package

ifeq ($(PLATFORM_VERSION), $(filter $(PLATFORM_VERSION),S 12))
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += CameraApp
  SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := newCameraTarget
else
  SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
  SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := oldCameraTarget
endif
```

**Android.bp**

```
// This introduces the module type camera_cc_defaults
// If target.mk file contained:
//
// SOONG_CONFIG_NAMESPACES += camera
// SOONG_CONFIG_camera += camtargets
// SOONG_CONFIG_camera_camtargets := newCameraTarget
//
// Then our libs would build with static_libs

soong_config_module_type {
    name: "camera_cc_defaults",
    module_type: "cc_defaults",
    config_namespace: "camera",
    variables: ["camtargets"],
    properties: ["static_libs"],
}

soong_config_string_variable {
    name: "camtargets",
    values: ["oldCameraTarget", "newCameraTarget"],
}

camera_cc_defaults {
    name: "camera_defaults",
    soong_config_variables: {
        camtargets: {
            oldCameraTarget: {
                static_libs: [
                ],
            },
            newCameraTarget: {
                static_libs: [
                    "androidx.core_core-ktx",
                    "androidx.fragment_fragment-ktx",
                    "androidx.navigation_navigation-fragment-ktx",
                    "androidx.navigation_navigation-ui-ktx",
                    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime-ktx",
                    "kotlinx_coroutines",
                    "kotlinx_coroutines_android",
                ],
            },
        },
    },
}

android_library {
  name: "utils",
  defaults: ["camera_defaults"],
  manifest: "utils/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
  platform_apis: true,

  srcs: [
    "utils/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/*.kt",
  ],

  resource_dirs: [
    "utils/src/main/res/",
  ],

  static_libs: [
    "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
    "androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager",
    "com.google.android.material_material",
    "androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface",
    "androidx.core_core",
    "androidx.preference_preference",
    "androidx.fragment_fragment",
    "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions",
    "kotlin-stdlib",
    "kotlin-reflect",
    "gson-prebuilt-jar",
  ],

  optimize: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}

android_app {
  name: "CameraApp",
  defaults: ["camera_defaults"],
  manifest: "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
  privileged: true,
  platform_apis: true,
  certificate: "platform",

  srcs: [
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/*.kt",
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/fragments/*.kt",
    "app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/overlay/*.kt",
  ],

  resource_dirs: [
    "app/src/main/res/",
  ],

  static_libs: [
    "androidx-constraintlayout_constraintlayout",
    "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
    "androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager",
    "com.google.android.material_material",
    "androidx.exifinterface_exifinterface",
    "androidx.core_core",
    "androidx.preference_preference",
    "androidx.fragment_fragment",
    "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime",
    "androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-extensions",
    "kotlin-stdlib",
    "kotlin-reflect",
    "gson-prebuilt-jar",
    "utils",
  ],

  optimize: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  dex_preopt: {
    enabled: false,
  },
}
```